# VBA code to copy a range of cells from previous sheet and import to a new sheet

Tags: excel

Apologies if this has been answered before but I want to copy a column to a new sheet using macros. How would this code be created if i need it to be done multiple times but referencing the last sheet. 
Example:
If I had 3 sheets, i want sheet2 to copy from sheet1 and sheet3 to copy from sheet2.

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super basic but here you go. This will copy sheet1 10 more times.

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
    For i = 1 To 10
        Sheets("Sheet" & i).Copy After:=Sheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```